# Operating Systems Virtual Memory

Tags: operating-system, system, theory

I am a student reading Operating systems course for the first time. I have a doubt in the calculation of the performance degradation calculation while using demand paging. In the Silberschatz book on operating systems, the following lines appear. 
"If we take an average page-fault service time of 8 milliseconds and a
memory-access time of 200 nanoseconds, then the effective access time in
nanoseconds is
    effective access time = (1 - p) x (200) + p (8 milliseconds)
    = (1 - p) x 200 + p x 8.00(1000
    = 200 + 7,999,800 x p.
We see, then, that the effective access time is directly proportional to the
page-fault rate. If one access out of 1,000 causes a page fault, the effective
access time is 8.2 microseconds. The computer will be slowed down by a factor
of 40 because of demand paging! "

How did they calculate the slowdown here? Is 'performance degradation' and slowdown the same?

Comment: 8.2 microseconds is roughly 40 times 200 nanoseconds.    8.2 microseconds is the average of 1000 time 200 nanoseconds plus 1 time 8 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is whole thing is nonsensical. It assumes a fixed page fault rate P. That is not realistic in itself. That rate is a fraction of memory accesses that result in a page fault.

1-P is the fraction of memory accesses that do not result in a page fault.

T= (1-P) x 200ns  + p (8ms) is then the average time of a memory access.
Expanded 
T = 200ns + p (8ms - 200ns)
T = 200ns + p (799980ns)

The whole thing is rather silly.

All you really need to know is a nanosecond is 1/billionth of a second.
A microsecond is 1/thousandth of a second.

Using these figures, there is a factor of a million difference between the access time in memory and in disk.